# Invisnik Laravel Steamauth login errors

Tags: laravel, steam

So I've just created a project in laravel 7 and added the [invisnik steamauth](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth) to it, I haven't added the actual auth package yet so that may be why I'm having the issue, however I don't want to lose what I've done.

I ran this migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id("steamid");
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->string('rank');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then I edited the create function in the steamauth controller to this:

```
return User::create([
        'username' => $info->personaname,
        'avatar' => $info->avatarfull,
        'steamid' => $info->steamID64,
        'rank' => 0
    ]);
```

When I go to login, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-05-06 18:32:42, 2020-05-06 18:32:42))
```

EDIT: Here's the User.php model

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like everything is getting stripped out of that `User::create()` call, aside from the auto-inserted timestamps. Can you post your `User.php` model?

Comment: i've edited the post

Comment: nevermind, fixed it. i see the mistake